# How to Select DFI, DFIIT, etc. with Scipy.Sigmal for IIR?

Tags: scipy, signal-processing

I am reading the API for scipy.signal ([docs.scipy.org](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html)) and I cannot find any function or parameter that allows me to select which of the 4 direct forms the resulting taps are for an IIR filter. Direct Form I, Direct Form II, etc. Does scipy.signal allow you to do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.9.0, [lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.9.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html#:%7E:text=The%20filter%20function%20is%20implemented%20as%20a%20direct%20II%20transposed%20structure).
operates using the Direct II transposed structure (I assume the same is true for other functions).

As far as I know you cannot specify the structure. The different structures should be equivalent, except for the numerical error accumulation, and for numerical robustness the recommendation is to use [sosfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfilt.html) instead.